# Cannot install numpy with Python 3.8 "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I tried EVERYTHING I've seen from similar questions on stack overflow and nothing seems to work... It may matter that I'm on a secure work computer, connected to a secured network, but I don't know if that has to do with anything.

I've added to "...Python\Python38\Scripts" and "...Python\Python38" to "Path" (among others) in my computer's Environment Variables (Start -> "Edit Environment Variables").

Here is what's entered on command line, just "pip install numpy":

C:\Users\bs>pip install numpy

Collecting numpy

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip. vendor.urllib3.connection. VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at Ox00000290E22FF550>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(pip. vendor.ur11ib3.connection. VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at @x00000290E22FF040>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection. VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at Ox00000290E22FF6A0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection. VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at Ox00000290E22FF820>, "Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip. vendor.urllib3.connection. VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at Ox00000290E22FF9A0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Comment: Sounds like you might need to check your proxy settings. Ask your colleagues about that - we don't know what that config should look like for you.

Comment: This is a network issue, nothing to do with Python, PyPI, or Numpy.